# How to Perform a Join Operation in Solr Using Regular Join Feature or what is the best practice for that?

Tags: java, performance, join, solr, nosql

I have two data structures in Solr representing parent-child (or 1 to 1) relationships, and I need to perform a join operation on these structures based on the fields. I understand that Solr doesn't directly support traditional joins like relational databases, but I'm looking for a way to achieve this join using Solr's built-in capabilities. e.g. include one document into another.

Is there a way to perform the join between these structures using Solr's regular join feature? If so, could you provide an example query or steps on how to set it up?

**Both documents are in the same core (collection).**

Any assistance in achieving this join operation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm currently attempting to perform a join operation in Solr using the {!join} query parser with the syntax {!join from=child_id to=parent_id}child_id:("111"). However, this approach doesn't seem to produce the expected results.

After some investigation, I discovered that Solr's join works differently, as explained in the official documentation here: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/join-query-parser.html.

I'm seeking assistance from the community to understand the correct way to perform a join using Solr's join query parser. Could someone provide an example or guide me on how to correctly set up the join operation based on the "child_id" and "parent_id" fields?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If they are parent/child-documents, you can use the child transformer or other existing parent/child support: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/searching-nested-documents.html - otherwise, the _absolutely_ easiest way to do this is to index everything as a single document (i.e. merge parent + child to a single document when indexing and not when searching - do as much work as possible up front).

Comment: Another approach is to use Result Grouping (https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/result-grouping.html)...it is NOT like a traditional join, but it can help you group documents together.

Comment: @MatsLindh good catch! Thank you, but the issue is that we have many documents already stored. Other ideas?

Comment: @HectorCorrea I don't think result grouping is a good idea because we need to make it possible for the UI to figure out where the parent and child documents are. (One-to-Many relationship). The grouping will constantly split results set by provided field, right?

Comment: The child transformer is probably the way to go then; in your question you said `1 to 1` relationship, but you mentioned 1:M here - so if you can't index your content in another way, I'd start there at least. But consider reindexing your existing content to fit with your query and faceting requirements in the future.

Comment: @MatsLindh Do I understand correctly, the parent/child transformer is only possible when you make embedding before the save the document, right? Thanks.

Comment: so like some kind of de-normalization and after you operate this documents?

Comment: @AlexanderTsukanov Good point, yes, I think you'd have to do that, so then you're back to having to reindex. The streaming expressions API should be an option even if you don't reindex - https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/stream-decorator-reference.html#innerjoin

Comment: @MatsLindh I have tried simple function `?expr=search(some_collection,q=*:*, fl="id", sort="id asc")` and got 
`
{
    "result-set": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "EXCEPTION": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.net.UnknownHostException: null: Name or service not known",
                "EOF": true,
                "RESPONSE_TIME": 6
            }
        ]
    }
}
`

Comment: Dot not understand where the problem is.

Comment: Are you running in SolrCloud mode or standalone?

Comment: @MatsLindh good question. Where I can check that?

Comment: It'll usually be visible in the Admin interface - quickest way is to see if there are collections listed (solrcloud) or cores (standalone).

Comment: @MatsLindh looks like they are listed as cores. I don't see some "solrcloud_" prefix or smth like that.

Comment: @MatsLindh any other possible options?

Comment: Not that I could think of; as far as i remember blockjoins needs to be indexed together/have proper nest paths / roots set as well. You'll probably have to reindex your content in some way to get what you're looking for.